# DGBMV issue with 2d array slice

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

I learn how to use blas and lapack libs in Fortran for operating with banded matrices. The code below I use to solve 2d heat equation by Peaceman‐Rachford schema, but I cut all not needed code.
What do I need? I need to multiply banded matrix coefficients on vector of function to get second derivative of the function.

I create two arrays: `test_array_col(2, N+1)` and `test_array_row(N+1, 2)` and `matrix band_matrix_y(3, N+1)`. I init array by 1.0. After calling

```
dgbmv('N', N+1, N+1, 1, 1, 1.0_dp, band_matrix_y, 3, test_array_col(1, :), 1, 1.0_dp, test_array_col(1, :), 1)
```

or

```
dgbmv('N', N+1, N+1, 1, 1, 1.0_dp, band_matrix_y, 3, test_array_row(:, 1), 1, 1.0_dp, test_array_row(:, 1), 1)
```

I expect get array where all elements are equal to 1.0, but I get this results only in first call.

The issue is that I need to store 2d array of my function and call `dgbmv` on each time step first for each row (work) and for each column (doesn't work). What can I do without transposing my 2d array of function on each time step? Of course I can implement this functionality myself, but I want to explain what happen below.

The whole code is here:

```
program dgbmv_issue
    implicit none

    integer, parameter:: N=10, M=10, dp=(kind(0.d0))
    double precision, dimension(:, :):: band_matrix_y(3, N+1), test_array_col(2, N+1), test_array_row(N+1, 2)
    integer:: i

    double precision:: DX, DY, L_X, L_Y, DT

    external:: dgbmv

    test_array_col = 1.0_dp
    test_array_row = 1.0_dp

    L_X = 1.0_dp
    L_Y = 1.0_dp

    DX = L_X / M
    DY = L_Y / N
    DT = 0.01_dp

    band_matrix_y = 0.0_dp

    band_matrix_y(1, 3:) = 0.5_dp * DT / DY / DY
    band_matrix_y(2, 2:N) = -DT / DY / DY
    band_matrix_y(3, :N-1) = 0.5_dp * DT / DY / DY

    open(1, file='out.txt')

    do i = 1, 3
        write(1, *) band_matrix_y(i, :)
    end do

    call dgbmv('N', N+1, N+1, 1, 1, 1.0_dp, band_matrix_y, 3, test_array_col(1, :), 1, 1.0_dp, test_array_col(1, :), 1)

    write(1, *) 'X'
    write(1, *) test_array_col(1, :)

    call dgbmv('N', N+1, N+1, 1, 1, 1.0_dp, band_matrix_y, 3, test_array_row(:, 1), 1, 1.0_dp, test_array_row(:, 1), 1)

    write(1, *) 'X'
    write(1, *) test_array_row(:, 1)

    close(1)

    
end program dgbmv_issue
```

And here's meson build file:

```
project('dgbmv_issue', 'fortran')
lapack = dependency('lapack')
blas = dependency('blas')
executable('dgbmv_issue', 'dgbmv_issue.f90', dependencies: [lapack, blas])
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please explain what exactly happens and what should happen instead. Do not use "it doesn't work", that does not say anything useful. What are your exact results you are getting? What results do you want to get instead of that?